# Determine which File we cannot find when opening two files

Tags: java

Is there a way I can print out just the which file we were not able to find in this scenario?

```
try{
        in1 = new Scanner(new File(inPath1)); 
        in2 = new Scanner(new File(inPath2));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("File not found: " e);
        System.exit(0);
}
```

This prints out:

```
File not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.dat (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

But I am only interested in the file name, not the entire string.

Comment: You could split it into two separate try catches

Comment: @dbrown93 Yes that was my last resort, but there must be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah with minor changes to your code as below:

```
String path = null; //track file name
try{
        in1 = new Scanner(new File(path = inPath1));
        in2 = new Scanner(new File(path = inPath2));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("File not found: " + path);//get recent file name
        System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. You could do it via parsing exception message. Here I used space delimeter to distinguish file name from other exception message, so I donn't expect file with space in name.

```
try{
        in1 = new Scanner(new File(inPath1));
        in2 = new Scanner(new File(inPath2));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        String message = e.getMessage();
        int i = message.indexOf(" ");
        String fileName = message.substring(0, i).trim();
        System.err.println("File not found: " + fileName);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had an array of file names you could do something like this

```
for(String s : a){
    try{
        files.add(new File(s));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("File not found: " + s);
    }
}
```